# Nextjs-blog tutorial not loading on localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Wanting to learn Nextjs and started by trying to go through the tutorial. Any time i 'npm run dev' local host just endlessly loads. When inspecting and checking the console I'm getting nothing at all.
Seems like nothing is coming back from the request.

Node version v16.13.1.

I've tried both `npx create-next-app nextjs-blog --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/master/basics/learn-starter"` & `npm init next-app nextjs-blog`.

Any help with this will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Waul are you trying to run the starter project "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/master/basics/learn-starter"?

Comment: @Loretta Yes I've tried to run the project that's on the Nextjs documentation.

Comment: @Loretta so it works on Safari but not firefox of Chrome. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: That's interesting. I cloned the repo at "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn" then moved to the learn-starter folder, did `npm install`, `npm run dev` and it worked fine for me on Chrome. Try to do a clean clone of the project again and see if it works. Sometimes this can happen because of faulty `node_modules` or `package-lock.json` so you can also try deleting both, before cloning the repo again, and running `npm install` again.

Comment: My node version is `v16.13.2`, npm is `v8.1.2`

Comment: @Loretta So it works on chrome now but still not on firefox. It's not ideal since firefox is the main browser I like to use but this'll do! Thanks for the hlep.

Comment: I'm very happy it works on Chrome now! You could also check if your apps and system are up to date and delete the browser cache if you haven't done that already.

Comment: @Loretta So i figured out the issue with firefox was that it was the only browser that wouldn't allow me to use the port without first doing 'npx kill-port #'. While the other browser didn't have that problem. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me

1. Delete the .next folder and try npm run dev command **OR**
2. Move the project to another folder location **OR**
3. Take back up of the code and delete the project and then run the same project again
4. You can try all of the above also

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually start the process with `npm run dev` command from your terminal.

Comment: Did this soluton work for u?

Comment: This will not work with NextJS apps. The dev environment is run with `npm run dev`. `npm start` runs the production build and can only be run after `npm run build`.

Comment: This doesn't work @Borecjeborec1. It gives me an "Unable to connect message" I'm guessing because it hasn't built like Loretta said.

Comment: @Loretta, Yes mb I edited the answer, this should work now.